# Using allocatable/assumed-size arrays with namelist read write

Tags: io, fortran, intel-fortran, fortran2003

I am using VS2012 and Intel Visual Fortran 2015.

According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/269585, it is now allowed to use allocatable and assumed-size arrays with namelist read and write; however, I am still getting the error "A namelist-group-object must not be an assumed-size array".

example code:

```
subroutine writeGrid(fname, grid)

    character*(*) :: fname
    real*8, dimension(:,:) :: grid

    namelist /gridNML/ grid

    open(1, file=fname)
    write(1, nml=gridNML)
    close(1)

end subroutine writeGrid
```

I have enabled F2003 Semantics.

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't have an allocatable array there.  Admittedly, you don't have an assumed-size array either.

Comment: The array being passed in is allocatable, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: The dummy argument of the subroutine is not allocatable. It does not matter that the passed array (actual argument) was allocatable. I also do not see any assumed size array as francescalus noted. Are you sure you are posting the exact code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a compiler bug.  The array `grid` is *assumed shape*, not *assumed size*.  Assumed shape arrays are permitted in namelist as of F2003, assumed size arrays remain prohibited (at runtime the size of an assumed size array is not necessarily known, so operations that require knowledge of the size are prohibited).

A simple workaround is to rename the dummy argument to something else and then copy its value into a local allocatable named `grid`.

```
subroutine writeGrid(fname, grid_renamed)
  character*(*) :: fname
  real, dimension(:,:) :: grid_renamed
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: grid

  namelist /gridNML/ grid

  open(1, file=fname)
  allocate(grid, source=grid_renamed)
  write(1, nml=gridNML)
  close(1)
end subroutine writeGrid
```

Comment: Ian is correct, this is a compiler bug. But it's NOT the case discussed in the forum topic you linked, which was a local, allocatable array. I will send this on to the developers.

Comment: Awesome. That's what I ended up figuring out as a workaround last night. Thank you, and thank you for pointing out the difference between assumed shape and assumed size.

Comment: I am told that this bug has been fixed. The fix should appear in Update 1 to the 16.0 compiler, probably in the October-November timeframe.